# Can/Should I Label an informational span for screen readers?

Tags: accessibility, html, screen-reader

I have an informational span, specifically, a span full of stars that represent a rating (star icons that can be filled or unfilled).  As is, it shouldn't be visible at all to a screen reader, since there is no text to read, but the information is important to a user.  I'm thinking of putting a label in that's only visible to screen readers.  From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), that seems like it's okay, since they say it

> represents a caption for an item in a user interface

and there is language that says it "can" be associated with a control, but none that it must be.  <strike>That makes sense, since you can associate a label with a `fieldset` as well as an `input`, but I'm not sure if that extends out to labeling a span.</strike> (as @Jukka notes, `label` is *not* appropriate for `fieldset`, I was thinking of `legend`)

Is labeling a span with equivalent information sufficient for a screen reader to see and use it?  Is that bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The `label` element is meant for labeling *controls* (form fields), and for them, it has support in user agents and in assistive software. Using it to label something else is illogical and most probably does not serve a useful purpose: either it is ignored, or it is implemented in a manner that makes the user think that it is associated with a control.

Formally, the close-to-de-facto-standard HTML5 CR says that the [`label` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) must be associated with a “labelable element”; this is defined so that e.g. `span` is not labelable (and neither is `fieldset`: a `label` element must label *a* control, not a set of controls).

The MDN site is not authoritative. Though generally very useful, it is misleading in this issue. The `label` element is not for labeling “user interface elements” in general.

The most accessible way to present ratings with stars is to use a separate image for each number of stars and an `alt` attribute that expresses the number in words, e.g. `<img alt="Three stars out of five" src=stars3.png>`. There are various other approaches. If you use a `span` element that you somehow format to look like some number of stars, then the technique most probably does not provide for good accessibility. If you have to work under such conditions, use a `title` attribute on that element, expressing the rating verbally. The attribute will be read by some software under some conditions.

Comment: the w3c link you included says "The label element represents a caption in a user interface." just like mdn

Comment: @albert, HTML5 documents might be a bit fuzzy in this issue, but the intent is that “user interface” refers to controls. A `label` element that is not associated with a labelable element has no *meaning* assigned to it.

Comment: right, but they don't have to be in a form or connected to a form....at least in html5...if i understand it correctly

Answer (score 0):

not disagreeing with @jukka's opinion on using `img /` elements, but here's another version using `input /`s http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/CGP87/light/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [role and aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Role_Img) properties.

Mozilla give this example : https://codepen.io/svinkle/pen/oYjoNE

Comment: Can you summarise what this is and why role / aria-label is needed? If you're linking off to an external source to provide the detail then that's not really answering the question, you're saying '*this place elsewhere is where you should go*'. As a repository for UX solutions, ux.stackexchange answers should all attempt to directly answer the questions. If that link goes down, or the site/page gets deleted then your answer here becomes totally useless. Links to external sites should be used as *citations / references*, not as *the* answer.